# Using Dataframe as RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to use a Dataframe as RDD. 
When using a map method and extracting elements, the "[" & "]" characters are also being extracted. How can I avoid this? Is there a mistake in my logic?
I am sharing the details.

**dateframe name is olympics**

```
scala> olympics.first
res1812: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [Michael Phelps,23,United States,2008,8/24/2008,Swimming,8,0,0,8]
```

**dataframe as rdd by using map method**

```
scala> olympics.map(x => x.toString.split(",")).first
res1814: Array[String] = Array([Michael Phelps, 23, United States, 2008, 8/24/2008, Swimming, 8, 0, 0, 8])
```

As you can see in the above result, the characters "["  "]" are also being extracted.

Expected result is:

```
Array[String] = Array(Michael Phelps, 23, United States, 2008, 8/24/2008, Swimming, 8, 0, 0, 8)
```

I do not want the first and last character from the row to be captured.
I tried using substring but its only extracting the first element.

How do i solve this?
Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing the data to output file or database you can make a `string` from that `array` of `string` without `"["` and `"]"` as below

```
olympics.map(x => x.mkString(",")).first
```

Hope this helps!